# jQuery: Highlight link that have the same href as another

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I'm working on a project, where I want to highlight the link (in a menu) that has the same href as another link on the site (in .container).

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="about.html">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="container">
    <a href="contact.html">Go to Contact</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    return this.href === $('.container a').href;
}).addClass("equalHref");
```

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is very nearly correct:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    // use jQuery.attr to access href
    return this.href === $('.container a').attr("href");
}).addClass("equalHref");
```

or:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    // expose DOM object and access href property
    return this.href === $('.container a')[0].href;
}).addClass("equalHref");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a:[href="' + $('.container a').attr("href") + '"]').addClass("equalHref");
```

Test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wgK8m/)

Comment: I am always late by 5 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

```
var strHref = $('.container a').attr("href");    
$("a[href=" + strHref  + "]")addClass("equalHref")
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8BRyG/

fiddle here.